# How to configure apache to use openssl-3

Tags: apache-2.4, openssl

I've installed openssl-3 inside my php-apache Docker container and I'd like to configure Apache to use openssl-3. Can someone please tell me how?

- openssl-3: installed from https://github.com/openssl/openssl, master
  branch
- Docker container: php:7.0.32-apache
  (https://hub.docker.com/_/php)
- Apache version: 2.4.25

Thanks!

Comment: Don't do that. A broken web site is the least you should expect to happen.

Comment: Thanks, @MichaelHampton. It is not for prod but for testing, and the purpose is to find out what is broken.